# Interact with Mail though UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uidocumentinteraction

I'm sharing a PDF to other apps through the `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Prior to adding this functionality, I had a custom 'send to email' button using the `MFMailComposeViewController` - yet now there's also a Mail button in my `UIDocumentInteractionController`, which I'd like to make use of, to avoid having duplicate buttons.

My issue is, through the old mail controller, I used to set a subject, and content text, whereas if I use the `UIDocumentInteractionController` - I only get a blank email with the PDF attachment. Does anyone know a way I could work round this and get my custom subject and content when using the `UIDocumentInteractionController`?

I couldn't find anything obvious in the documentation, and clearly I can't meddle with the Mail app to make it communicate with my app - but wondered if anyone else had encountered the problem, and sussed out a 'back-door' solution.

Below is the code for how I'm currently creating and initalising my `UIDocumentInteractionController`:

```
-(void)openDocumentIn:(NSString*)filepath
{

    //NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                  pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"pdf"];
    documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController 
                         interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath]];
    documentController.delegate = self;
    documentController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";
    [documentController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:
         [self.imageViewController exportQuote] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: @windup unfortunately not - still an unanswered question!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the following code

```
[self.documentInteractionController setName:@"My Email Subject"];
```

Comment: The question was about setting mail composer's properties. setName: will set instead the UIDocumentInteractionController's title in the navigation bar but not the mail's subject.